# C# - Can't resolve XInput namespace in DirectX SDK (November 2008)

Tags: c#, directx, controller, xbox, xinput

I'm just starting to play around with directx and I've read a few articles on the internet that use XInput to interface with the Xbox controller.

When I try to use it in my c# app, I can't seem to find the correct assembly to reference.  From what I understand, it's supposed to be in `Microsoft.DirectX.dll` (namespace `Microsoft.DirectX.XInput`) but that doesn't get resolved when I add the reference.

Am I missing something? Should I try an earlier version of the sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an excellent 3rd-party wrapper around DirectX for .Net called SlimDX: http://slimdx.mdxinfo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

It's very similar to Managed DX. I've been using it for a couple months now with 0 problems.

Comment: thanks, slimdx seems to do the job perfectly fine and it's a 30meg download as opposed to 450meg :) still gonna play around with XNA but for now slimdx meets my needs perfectly.

Comment: Even better, the SlimDX redistributable package is only 8mb, and it includes DirectX as well!

Answer (score 2):

It seems odd here. Microsoft doesn't provide managed directx anymore, and I've just check my reference list, there's no Microsoft.DirectX.XInput for managed library. Most like it's only available for C++ and XNA only.